# Bagging method in WEKA with one classifier

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

Bagging is an example of an ensemble method. In this method, the training dataset has been divided into several subsets with replacements. Also, there are several numbers of classifiers' models. A classifier model, Mi, is learned for each training set, Di. To classify an unknown tuple, X, each classifier, Mi, returns its class prediction, which counts as one vote. The bagged classifier, M∗, counts the votes and assigns the class with the most votes to X.

So, from the above definition, it is clear bagging works on more than one classifier. I am working with WEKA software and using Bagging for classification. I found I can only input one classifier from the property window of bagging.

[image]

If bagging works on different classifiers then why bagging on WEKA does not have an option for multiple classifiers input?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Bagging uses the same classifier template for all the classifiers in its ensemble (`numIterations` = size of ensemble). Hence you can only define a single classifier.

[Breiman's paper](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/bagging.pdf) never stated that Bagging would use different predictors, only that *the vital element is the instability of the prediction method*.

See also [sklearn's implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html).

If you want to create an ensemble with different base classifiers, then use Weka's [Vote](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/Vote.html) meta classifier.